# UnicodeDecodeError error when loading word2vec

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim, python-unicode, polyglot

**Full Description**

I am starting to work with word embedding and found a great amount of information about it. I understand, this far, that I can train my own word vectors or use previously trained ones, such as Google's or Wikipedia's, which are available for the English language and aren't useful to me, since I am working with texts in *Brazilian Portuguese*. Therefore, I went on a hunt for pre-trained word vectors in Portuguese and I ended up finding [Hirosan's List of Pretrained Word Embeddings](http://ahogrammer.com/2017/01/20/the-list-of-pretrained-word-embeddings/) which led me to Kyubyong's [WordVectors](https://github.com/Kyubyong/wordvectors) from which I learned about Rami Al-Rfou's [Polyglot](https://sites.google.com/site/rmyeid/projects/polyglot). After downloading both, I unsuccessfully have been trying to simply load the word vectors.

**Short Description**

I can't load pre-trained word vectors; I am trying [WordVectors](https://github.com/Kyubyong/wordvectors) and [Polyglot](https://sites.google.com/site/rmyeid/projects/polyglot).

**Downloads**

- [Kyubyong's pre-trained word2vector format word vectors for Portuguese](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0ZXk88koS2KRDcwcV9IVWFTeUE);
- [Polyglot's pre-trained word vectors for Portuguese](https://doc-0g-54-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/c1ch6rdnp89glqmi8g81ev2somslu7cs/1527537600000/10341224892851088318/*/0B5lWReQPSvmGNEh0VTdmSHlHZ1k?e=download);

**Loading attempts**

*Kyubyong's [WordVectors](https://github.com/Kyubyong/wordvectors)*
First attempt: using Gensim as suggested by [Hirosan](http://ahogrammer.com/2017/01/20/the-list-of-pretrained-word-embeddings/);

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
kyu_path = '.../pre-trained_word_vectors/kyubyong_pt/pt.bin'
word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(kyu_path, binary=True)
```

And the error returned:

```
[...]
File "/Users/luisflavio/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 359, in any2unicode
return unicode(text, encoding, errors=errors)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

The zip downloaded also contains other files but all of them return similar errors.

*[Polyglot](https://sites.google.com/site/rmyeid/projects/polyglot)*
First attempt: following [Al-Rfous's instructions](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/aboSamoor/6046170);

```
import pickle
import numpy
pol_path = '.../pre-trained_word_vectors/polyglot/polyglot-pt.pkl'
words, embeddings = pickle.load(open(pol_path, 'rb'))
```

And the error returned:

```
File "/Users/luisflavio/Desktop/Python/w2v_loading_tries.py", line 14, in <module>
    words, embeddings = pickle.load(open(polyglot_path, "rb"))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Second attempt: using [Polyglot's word embedding load function](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Embeddings.html);

First, we have to install polyglot via pip:

```
pip install polyglot
```

Now we can import it:

```
from polyglot.mapping import Embedding
pol_path = '.../pre-trained_word_vectors/polyglot/polyglot-pt.pkl'
embeddings = Embedding.load(polyglot_path)
```

And the error returned:

```
File "/Users/luisflavio/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

**Extra Information**

I am using python 3 on MacOS High Sierra.

**Solutions**

*Kyubyong's [WordVectors](https://github.com/Kyubyong/wordvectors)*
As pointed out by [Aneesh Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50579950?noredirect=1), the correct way to load Kyubyong's model is by calling the native load function of Word2Vec.

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
kyu_path = '.../pre-trained_word_vectors/kyubyong_pt/pt.bin'
model = Word2Vec.load(kyu_path)
```

Even though I am more than grateful for Aneesh Joshi solution, polyglot seems to be a better model for working with Portuguese. Any ideas about that one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Kyubyong's pre-trained word2vector .bin file:
it may have been saved using gensim's save function.

"load the model with `load()`. Not `load_word2vec_format` (that's for the C-tool compatibility)."

i.e., `model = Word2Vec.load(fname)`

Let me know if that works.

Reference : [Gensim mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gensim/gZ0BRnETMnw/m4WnXSyZFdcJ)

Comment: Hello, @aneeshjoshi and thanks for your reply! You are right about how to fix the problem with Kyubyong's pre-trained word2vector. I now understand the difference between `load_word2vec_format()` and `load()`; thanks for that. As I mentioned in the post update, polyglot is more reliable, do you happen to know what is going on with that one?