# Error when loading .bin embedding file using gensim package

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I tried to load .bin embedding file using gensim but i got  errors. I tried all the methods provided by gensim but couldn't rectify the error

**Method 1**

```
import gensim.models.keyedvectors as word2vec

model=word2vec.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('Health_2.5reviews.s200.w10.n5.v10.cbow.bin', binary=True, unicode_errors=‘ignore')
```

**Method 2**

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

filename='Health_2.5reviews.s200.w10.n5.v10.cbow.bin'

model=KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(filename,binary=True,unicode_errors=‘ignore')
```

**Method 1 and 2 gave the error**

> "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position
>   0: invalid start byte"

**Method 3**

```py
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

filename='Health_2.5reviews.s200.w10.n5.v10.cbow.bin'

model=Word2Vec.load(filename)
```

**Method 3 gave the error**

> UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xbc'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError error when loading word2vec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50573054/unicodedecodeerror-error-when-loading-word2vec)

Comment: I tried Word2Vec.load() method also, but I got another error **UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xbc'.**

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022180/unpickling-error-while-using-word2vec-load

Comment: Thanks @amanb. I will check.

Comment: How were the models saved, or from where were they sourced? 

Are you sure the models haven't been corrupted/truncated?

Comment: @gojomo   I think, the model is corrupted. I'm in the process of generating embeddings again with gensim.